# Ruby : How to make a HttpRequest

Tags: http, ruby-1.9.2, rails-3.1

I'm still new in ruby, please help.
I'm trying to make a http request in my standalone ruby script.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/http'
...
class someClass
...
def get_ruby_doc
  request = HttpRequest.new(:get, 'http://www.ruby-doc.org/')
  response = request.perform!
  puts response.succeeded?
  puts "yeah"
end
...
```

when I run the script, I get this error:

```
Uncaught exception: uninitialized constant someClass::HttpRequest
```

Can you please let me know what did I miss?  Thanks.

I also try to do the same in rails console, same error.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using rest-client

```
gem install rest-client
```

http://rubydoc.info/gems/rest-client/1.6.7/frames